# It possible to change the bootstrap classes direction?

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass, bootstrap-4

I'm using Bootstrap 4 [lib](https://getbootstrap.com/) to handle spacing (margins & paddings) in a static website using bootstrap [classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/spacing/).

Example:

```
<p class="mr-3">Lorem ...</p>
```

Now, What if I need to change the HTML direction from *ltr* to *rtl* ? In my case the mr-* should be ml-*.

So how to handle this?

Must I override the bootstrap classes? or bootsrap having something to solve this issue?

If I should override the bootstrap classes, any way to change the margin direction only?

> Note: I'm using SASS

Thanks.

Comment: take a look here : http://bootstrap.rtlcss.com/

Comment: the idea is to load your css file depending on your site language  using javascript . if you are intresting in that way , i can give you an example

Comment: Thanks for your answare, I downloaded the boostrap.rtlcss and is reverting the directions, but isn't overridden the original one even though the resources order is correct

Comment: @MohammedYassineCHABLI If I find a solution for the override aspect. that's solve my problem.

Comment: Hi! I notice you're new but you sound experienced. I would recommend, from personal experience, not using bootstrap and instead making your own css framework based heavily off of `flex` and `@media (max-width: ...)`. which is basically the only real reason people come to bootstrap : for responsive design. which I find with a tad bit of elbow grease you can come up with a css framework that is worth the time investment and won't cause you the headaches boostrap does. Bootstrap thinks things like per-browser implementation of css spec implementation and DPI don't exist.

Comment: @tatsu  Agreed! But now I can't update my code for timing reason. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add another class with the margin direction that suites you and make the margin-left: 100px for example margin-left: 100px!important , this will overrule the margin of the bootstrap class

Answer (score 0):

I am creating other helpers to get reverse those styles, something like this

```
[dir="rtl"]{
   .ml-2{
      margin-right: .5rem !important;
      margin-left: 0!important;      
   }
}
```